# How can I combine multiple where (and or) statements?

Tags: sas

I can get my code to work but only if I split it into two data steps.  When I combine, I get an empty set as a result.  Ultimately I want one month of data, but only the record that contains one of 6 keywords.

Example of code that does not work:

```
data d_prep;

    set DataTable;
    where
                    (CREATIONTIME ge "01DEC2017"d) and (CREATIONTIME le "31DEC2017"d)

                    and

                    (TEXT           contains    'Initialize VNC'
                or  TEXT            contains    'FT-Download'
                or  TEXT            contains    'FT-Upload'
                or  TEXT            contains    'Remote Session'
                or  TEXT            contains    'Login of user'
                or  TEXT            contains    'Create AdHoc-Action');
run;
```

This gives me zero observations.  However, if I split into two steps, I get it to work:

```
data d_prep;

    set DataTable
    where
                    (CREATIONTIME ge "01DEC2017"d) and (CREATIONTIME le "31DEC2017"d);

run;

data d_prep_1;

    set d_prep;
    where       
                    TEXT            contains    'Initialize VNC'
                or  TEXT            contains    'FT-Download'
                or  TEXT            contains    'FT-Upload'
                or  TEXT            contains    'Remote Session'
                or  TEXT            contains    'Login of user'
                or  TEXT            contains    'Create AdHoc-Action';      

    run;
```

Comment: Those should work as expected, can you include your log from the queries.

Comment: The log is too long.  There are no errors, only that there were no observations.

I've tried many different configurations of or's & and's and none of them work. I can get the program to work if I leave out the latter date in the where clause, but then I end up with data after the date range I'm looking for.

Is there a way I can try this with IF statements?

Comment: The log from the shown code should be fairly short. Sure you can change to IF, but in theory it shouldn't change the results, so either the issue is further or something else that's not shown.  Replace WHERE with IF and the CONTAINS with the FIND() or INDEX() functions.

Comment: Try it with IF instead of WHERE.  It might make a difference if you are pulling data from a view in a database that is doing a poorly constructed join.

Comment: What version of SAS? Is the data set accessed through a remote library engine? What is the encoding of the data set? What is the encoding of the SAS session? Is the session encoding default (English), DBCS or Unicode? How about the log of the single data step that does not subset as expected, the section that shows the where clause performed. "NOTE: There were 0 observations read from the data set DataTable.  WHERE ..."
-- surely that is not too long

Comment: Here's the section of the long that pertains to the problem.  FWIW, yes, this is pulling from a view.

NOTE: There were 0 observations read from the data set DataTable
      WHERE (CREATIONTIME>='01DEC2017'D and CREATIONTIME<='31DEC2017'D) and (TEXT contains 'Initialize VNC' or TEXT contains 
      'FT-Download' or TEXT contains 'FT-Upload' or TEXT contains 'Remote Session' or TEXT contains 'Login of user' or TEXT 
      contains 'Create AdHoc-Action');
NOTE: The data set WORK.D_PREP has 0 observations and 5 variables.

Comment: Is the view a SQL view or a DATA Step view? Does the view use a remote library? If you have access to the view source do you get the same no rows situation by adding your 3 criteria directly to it?  If the view source is a lot of code try making test views that whittle down parts until correct operation is observed. Update question with an 'also tried' section to convey new information, that makes it easier for future potential respondents.If security policies prevent showing critical details you should contact support.sas.com directly. If you figure it out, answer your own question :)

Comment: Do you get same 'no rows' when using (CREATIONTIME BETWEEN "01DEC2017"d and "31DEC2017"d) and .. ( ... contains criteria ... ) ?

Comment: I replaced the or's and contains with the following and it worked:

if find(TEXT,'Login of user') then output;
if find(TEXT,'Remote Session') then output;

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Good day, Since you are using where environment, I found cool feature `?` it essentially is contains:

```
data wanted; 
    set begin; 
    where var1 <10000 and var2=2016 and (TEXT  ? 'mobile' or TEXT ? 'scout'); 
run;
```

I tested this with data and seems to be working.

Check the [SaS documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lestmtsref&docsetTarget=n1xbr9r0s9veq0n137iftzxq4g7e.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n0xj2ds84r7zqyn1h2n50h959xhh) for this trick.